# Grab attribute of element clicked - using on click event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

In my html I have a screen with with about 25 thumbnails, and each of them has a like button in the format:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="likeBtn" data-id="545206032225604" value="Like">
```

Where data-id is different for each image.

The idea is to then use that id to make a POST request to the facebook graph API and like the post.

I have a event listener like so:

```
$('#likeBtn').click(function () {
    facebook.likePhoto(controller.likeReady);
});
```

The issue I am having is I am unsure how to grab that data-id from the element that is actually clicked.

Let me know if I can provide any more information.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$('#likeBtn').click(function () {
    var data_id = $(this).data('id'); 
    facebook.likePhoto(controller.likeReady);
});
```

Read [this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Id attribute must be unique . Use classes Instead.

**change HTML**

Use class `likeBtn` instead of id `likeBtn` as you said you have many buttons like this .

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small likeBtn" data-id="545206032225604" value="Like">
```

Noe your `js` becomes

```
$('.likeBtn').click(function () {
    var data_id = $(this).data('id'); 
    facebook.likePhoto(controller.likeReady);
});
```

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

**Updated after OP's comment**

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on('click','.likeBtn',function () {
    var data_id = $(this).data('id'); 
    facebook.likePhoto(controller.likeReady);
});
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Comment: Okay so I have gone and changed it to a class like above and removing the id="likeBtn".

However I am now realising my event handler isn't even registering the click, so the code never gets executed.

    $('.likeBtn').click(function () {
  var data_id = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(data_id);
        //facebook.likePhoto(controller.likeReady);
    });

Is there anything you can see wrong with the handler itself, or any idea what else can cause this?

Comment: Sorry didn't realise the comment would be so awfully formatted, my bad.

Comment: @Reece Are these like buttons are generated dynamically ?

Comment: Yes, I make a request to facebook, pull down all the photos for the thumbnails. Store them in a object and then run them through my view.displayProducts(). which loops through and modifies the HTML content of my thumbnails section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#likeBtn').click(function () {
    var dataId = $(this).prop('data-id');
    console.log(dataId); //or do something else

    facebook.likePhoto(controller.likeReady);
});
```

Though, if I understand this correctly, do you have multiple elements with the id likeBtn?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#likeBtn').click(function () {
   var id;

   id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   facebook.likePhoto(controller.likeReady);
});
```